# ASP.NET MVC - NumberDecimalSeparator not affected by Culture change

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added this in my web.config :

```
<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr-FR" />
```

But when I check `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` it's always set to `dot` when it should be a `comma`

Isn't setting the culture in web.config sufficient ? Should I set the number decimal separator manually ?

**EDIT :**

I noticed something really weird : Both my local machine and the server have this in the web.config :

```
<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr-FR" />
```

But on my local machine `NumberDecimalSeparator` is a comma `,`
And on the server `NumberDecimalSeparator` is a dot `.`

I checked to see if may be the culture setting in web.config wasn't applied but `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture` showed `fr-FR` on both my local machine and the server

????

Comment: `<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr" />`

Comment: uiCulture is only responsible for Resources

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the UI culture in web config like this :

```
<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr" />
```

If this doesn't work, then try this explicitly inside the controller action method :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

This should work if the culture of the current thread is causing the issue.